# Reopen closed tabs in Google Chrome not working. Getting stuck on one tab

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to re-open closed tabs in Google Chrome, which normally works fine.  But this time, it is getting stuck on a tab that downloaded a piece of software so that every time I hit 'reopen closed tab' it keeps trying to reopen this same website. I have tried deleting this website from my history but that doesn't help. Can someone help me solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: The best solution for something like that is saving your bookmarks (and anything else you might want to keep) and do a clean install of chrome. Maybe also try completely clearing the browser cache.